# D3D11.1 Running Out of Memory While Resizing Window?

Tags: visual-c++, out-of-memory, directx-11

I am struggling to solve this issue; using D3D11.1 and a standard Win32 desktop window, I get out of memory errors while resizing my window, but only while resizing manually for a few seconds. Maximizing works fine, and resizing very fast works fine. It is as if something is continually being allocated during manual resizing, but I cannot figure out what it is.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcessWindow(HWND hWnd, uint32 nMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(nMessage)
{
case WM_SIZE:
    OnResize();
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, nMessage, wParam, lParam);
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, nMessage, wParam, lParam);
}



void OnResize()
{
    ResizeSwapChain();
    ResetRenderTargets();
    ResetDepthStencil();
}



void ResizeSwapChain()
{
if(m_pD3DSwapChain)
{
    m_D3DDepthStencilView.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();
    m_pD3DRenderTarget.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();

    //THE SWAP CHAIN ALREADY EXISTS, RESIZE IT
    DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(nBufferCount, 0, 0, SwapChainFormat, 0));
} 
}



bool ResetRenderTargets()
{
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> B;
DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&B)));

DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(B.Get(), nullptr, &m_pD3DRenderTarget));

B.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();

if(!m_pD3DRenderTarget)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}



bool ResetDepthStencil()
{
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC BBD;

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> B;
DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&B)));

B->GetDesc(&BBD);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC DSD; //DEPTH STENCIL DESC
memset(&DSD, 0, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));

DSD.Width               = BBD.Width;
DSD.Height              = BBD.Height;
DSD.MipLevels           = 1;
DSD.ArraySize           = 1;
DSD.Format              = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
DSD.SampleDesc.Count    = 1;
DSD.SampleDesc.Quality  = 0;
DSD.Usage               = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
DSD.BindFlags           = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
DSD.CPUAccessFlags      = 0;
DSD.MiscFlags           = 0;

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> DS;
DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&DSD, nullptr, &DS));

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC DVD;
memset(&DVD, 0, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));

DVD.Format              = DSD.Format;
DVD.ViewDimension       = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
DVD.Flags               = 0;
DVD.Texture2D.MipSlice  = 0;

DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(DS.Get(), &DVD, &m_D3DDepthStencilView));

B.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();
DS.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf();

if(!m_D3DDepthStencilView)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}


bool ResetViewports()
{
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC BBD; //BACK BUFFER DESC
memset(&BBD, 0, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> B;
DXErrorOnFail(m_pD3DSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&B)));

B->GetDesc(&BBD);

D3D11_VIEWPORT V;
V.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
V.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
V.Width    = static_cast<float32>(BBD.Width);
V.Height   = static_cast<float32>(BBD.Height);
V.MinDepth = D3D11_MIN_DEPTH;
V.MaxDepth = D3D11_MAX_DEPTH;

m_pD3DDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &V);

return true;
}
```

I truly appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reallocating during resize is not a good idea for few reasons:

- You gonna destroy and recreate resources a LOT (and in this case it's a simple example, think about a complex app with lot of intermediate textures).
- DX doesn't destroy resources immediately when you call ReleaseAndGetAddressOf, it will do it the next time you flush the buffer, since while you resize you will probably not render, the context won't be flushed.

One cleaner solution is to use Begin/EndResize events.
[WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
[WM_EXITSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Set a flag on enter message, and apply your changes on exit.